# MySQL Community Edition

Tags: mysql, version

I have recently inherited a MySQL database, installed on AWS, in the Community Edition. The MySQL website has information about the features of MySQL Community, but it doesn't tie it to any versions, at least not that I can find.

Does the Community Version (free) have the same version numbers as the Server Version (proprietary)?

Or, am I completely missing how the versioning works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MySQL Community Edition and Enterprise Edition have the same version numbers. The current version of both today is 8.0.18.

In fact, the Community and Enterprise editions are exactly the same software. Well, the Enterprise gives you access to some supplementary tools and plugins, but the RDBMS itself is the same.

The main difference between Community and Enterprise editions is the software license, not the technology.

- Community edition is licensed under the GNU Public License (GPL), which defines some conditions on users who distribute the software. You can use it for free, but if you distribute it with your own software product, your product must itself have a GPL-compatible license.
- Enterprise edition is a commercial license you have to pay for, but you get the privilege to distribute MySQL Server without the obligations of the GPL.